# How to make circle movement in matrix in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a code where number 1 must replace 0 by row as pointed below:

[image]

Here's the code of it:

```
int field[y][x] =
{
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0}
};
 
int main() 
{
    showField();                //Show field
    cout << endl;
    again:
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            if (j > 0)
            {
                field[i][j - 1] = 0;
            }
            field[i][j] = 1;
            countTimeSec();         //updates the board per second
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            field[i][y - 1] = 0;
            goto again;
        }
        else 
        {
            field[i][y - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    showField();
    return 0;
}
void countTimeSec() 
{
    int oneSec = 0;
    while (oneSec < 15)
    {
        showField(); 
        oneSec++; 
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how to modify the code to make algorithm like this:
[image]

If there will be any logic how to make it, I will also appreciate that

Comment: Avoid using `goto` when there are other(better) alternatives available. Looks like you're not using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is steve prata's book so bad?

Comment: *"Is steve prata's book so bad? ..."* I would definitely say so(assuming by steve you mean stephen).

Comment: If the book taught you to use `goto`, then it is safe to conclude it's terrible.

Comment: If you have no idea how to do it, hardcode it first. Then observe the pattern in the array indexes. Gradually improve your code by using loops. You will get there.

Comment: @user12002570 I think it's very complicated for beginners to understand how the language works. The book doesn't say that it's better to use **goto**, it just says that there is a way to make the same without loops

Comment: Prata's "C++ Primer Plus" has a pretty terrible reputation. The title is a quite obvious attempt to suggest that it's an improvement of Lippman's "C++ Primer", which it isn't.

Comment: @Hayk The best(without any doubt) beginner c++ book is "c++ primer by lippman 5th edition". There are pdf available if you search that term on google etc.

Comment: Is there any places to practice c++, do exercises and etc. for beginners?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, think about how you would rotate numbers in a 1D array. When rotating the matrix shown in your picture, you're basically rotating:

```
input:  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
output: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

For a single-element rotation, the approach is:

1. let `x` be the last element
2. shift all elements to the right by one
3. set the first element to `x`

In 2D, you're doing exactly the same thing, except that you have to map the 2D positions onto 1D positions:

```cpp
enum { x = 3, y = 3  };

int matrix[y][x] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {8, 0, 4},
    {7, 6, 5}
};

int* at_circumference(int i) {
    // {a, a, b}
    // {d, -, b}
    // {d, c, c}

    if (i < x - 1) return &matrix[0][    i]; // a
    i -= x - 1;
    if (i < y - 1) return &matrix[i][x - 1]; // b
    i -= y - 1;
    if (i < x - 1) return &matrix[y - 1][x - i - 1]; // c
    i -= x - 1;
    if (i < y - 1) return &matrix[y - i - 1][0]; // d
    
    exit(1); // index out of bounds
}
```

With this, the rotation can be implemented in 1D:

```cpp
const int circumference = (y - 1 + x - 1) * 2;

void rotate(void) {
    int last = *at_circumference(circumference - 1);
    for (int i = circumference - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        *at_circumference(i) = *at_circumference(i - 1);
    }
    *at_circumference(0) = last;
}
```

Lastly, some driver code:

```cpp
void print_circumference(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < circumference; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", *at_circumference(i));
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(void) {
    print_circumference();
    rotate();
    print_circumference();
}
```

The program outputs (https://godbolt.org/z/Ghr5bqbGc):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

#### Further Notes

Avoid backwards-`goto` if possible.
In your original code, which was of the form:

```cpp
again:
for (/* ... */) {
   // ...
   if (/* ... */) goto again;
}
```

... you could have instead written:

```cpp
while (1) {
    for (/* ... */) {
        if (/* ... */) goto again;
    }
    break;
    again: continue;
}
```

While this may seem more complex at first, the `while (1)` loop makes it immediately clear that repetition is going on, and in what scope.

In this case, you can also avoid `goto` entirely by having a

```cpp
bool is_continue = false;
```

... variable, which you update during the `for` loop and check in the surrounding `while` loop.